# Is there a way to detect when a workflow property changes for out of the box workflows in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti, bpmn

I want to be able to detect when a workflow task on a document that has been approved in a script action in share for the out-of-the-box workflows. Can't think of how to go about this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by changing process definition file for that particular workflow.

Inject your piece of script in transition to approve status which could notify you via email.
You will get it easily on google.

Mind this you will have to change reploy value as true for that particular workflow in workflow bootstrap xml file and restart the server.

NOTE: It will not affect inflight workflow instances.